# How to work with a Spark RDD to produce or map to another RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce

I have a Key/Value RDD I want to take that "iterate over" the entities in it, Key/Value, and create, or map, to another RDD which could have more or less entries that the first RDD.

Example:

I have records in accumulo that represent observations of colors in paintings.
An observation entity/object holds data on the painting name and the colors in the painting.

```
Observation
public String getPaintingName() {return paintingName;}
public List<String> getObservedColors() {return colorList}
```

I pull the observations from accumulo into my code as an RDD.

```
val observationRDD: RDD[(Text, Observation)] = getObservationsFromAccumulo();
```

I want to take this RDD and create an RDD of the form of (Color, paintingName) where the key is the color observed and the value is the painting name which the color was observed in.

```
 val colorToPaintingRDD: RDD[(String, String)] = observationRDD.somefunction({ case (_, observation) =>
    for(String color : observations.getObservedColors()) {
       // Some how output a entry into a new RDD
       //output/map (color, observation.getPaintingName)
 })
```

I know map can't work, because its 1 to 1, I thought maybe observationRDD.flatmap(some function) but can't seem to find any examples on how to do that to create a new, larger or smaller, RDD.

Could someone help me out and tell me if flatmap is correct, and if so give me an example using this example I provided, or tell me if i'm way off base?

Please understand this is just a simple example, its not the content im asking about, its how one would transform a RDD to a RDD with more or less entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use flatmap and return a List[(String, String)] foreach element in RDD. FlatMap will flat the result and you'll get an RDD[(String, String)]

I didn't try the code, but it would be something like this:

```
val colorToPaintingRDD: RDD[(String, String)] = observationRDD.flatMap { case (_, observation) =>
    observations.getObservedColors().map(color => (color, observation.getPaintingName))
}
```

Probably if getObservedColors method is in Java you have to import JavaConversions and change to scala list.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
observations.getObservedColors().toList
```